# insert many records inside a foreach - only the last one is added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to copy records from one "table" to another in firebase.

```
// copy posts to feed
var recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('user-posts').child(pid).limitToLast(10);
recentPostsRef.once('value', async function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
        var value = subChild.val();

        var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];

        var postData = {
            postID: key,
            user: pid
        };

        var updates2 = {};
        updates2['/feed/' + userID + '/' + key] = postData;

        firebase.database().ref().update(updates2);

    });

});
```

So I get posts from `user-posts` and try to copy the last 10 to `feed`. It is working, but only for 1 record. Any ideas why and how to copy all records instead of only one?

Comment: If you `console.log(JSON.stringify(updates2))` right before you call `update()`, what does it show?

Comment: Also: what is this line meant to accomplish? `var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
var recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('user-posts').child(pid).limitToLast(10);
recentPostsRef.once('value', async function(snapshot) {

    var updates2 = {};
    snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
        var key = subChild.key;

        var postData = {
            postID: key,
            user: pid
        };

        updates2['/feed/' + userID + '/' + key] = postData;
    });

    firebase.database().ref().update(updates2);
});
```

The changes I made:

- Get the key from `subChild.key`, instead of through a more complex lookup.
- Move the `update(...)` call outside of the loop, so that you only write to the database once for all 10 items.
- Since you weren't using the `value`, I removed that variable.

Note that we have no way to know what value `userID` has, so I just assumed that that part was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this perhaps?

```
snapshot.forEach((subChild, index) => {
                var value = subChild.val();

                var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[index];

                var postData = {
                    postID: key,
                    user: pid
                };

                var updates2 = {};
                updates2['/feed/' + userID + '/' + key] = postData;

                firebase.database().ref().update(updates2);

            });
```

You keep reusing the same index (0) for every loop.

Are you sure this is correct?
`var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[index];`

Should it not be something like: `var key = Object.keys(subChild.val())[index];` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but not working... not even saving any data... `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'feed.T87u4DL82IaGO9XOzsASxGdP7My2.undefined.postID'`

Comment: maybe another way to get this index should work... because when I console log the key, it console the same key many times...

Comment: `var key = subChild.key;` worked! thanks for your help!